# Node - Protractor "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when switching to ES6 modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

To run my tests I use

```
protractor conf.js
```

I get

```
File 'main' needs function 'httpGet' from file 'support.js'
```

In 'main' I changed from

```
const { httpGet } = require('./support');
```

to

```
import { httpGet } from './support';
```

and in the support file from

```
exports.httpGet = (siteUrl) => {
```

to

```
export function httpGet(siteUrl) {
```

but I get

```
import { httpGet } from ('./support');
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I tried using .mjs extensions, adding `"type": "module"` in my `package.json`  file but they all give the same error.  Where do I put the import? I currently have it within a specific `it` example, is that ok?'

Note that I don't run the node command directly, i use

```
protractor conf.js
```

Answer (score 2):

Update 3: Since Node 13, you can use either the .mjs extension or set "type": "module" in your package.json. You don't need to use the --experimental-modules flag.

Update 2: Since Node 12, you can use either the .mjs extension or set "type": "module" in your package.json. And you need to run node with the --experimental-modules flag.

Update: In Node 9, it is enabled behind a flag, and uses the .mjs extension.

node --experimental-modules my-app.mjs

While import is indeed part of ES6, it is unfortunately not yet supported in NodeJS by default, and has only very recently landed support in browsers.

If you really want to use new ES6/7 features in NodeJS, you can compile it using Babel.

Comment: I tried using mjs, i tried using type: module and i used --experimental-flag but I keep getting the SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module message.  Part of the challenge is that I am using a protractor command, not a node command directly

Answer (score 1):

**Node.js has included experimental support for ES6 support. Read more about here:** https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/esm.html#esm_enabling
**Node >= v13**

**Save the file with .mjs extension, or
Add type as module in the nearest package.json.
Node < v12**

**Save the file with ES6 modules with .mjs extension and run it like:
node --experimental-modules my-app.mjs**